# image in new xaml from images of a griview xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

image in new xaml from images of a griview xamarin forms

I would like to open the grid image in a new xaml below is the simple and good code:
I know it's easy and uses intent, but I can't find anything on the forum, can anyone help?
in xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinRocket.ViewModel;assembly=XamarinRocket" x:DataType="local:XamarinRocket2ViewModel"
             x:Class="XamarinRocket.Views.XamarinRocket2Page">
    
        <ContentPage.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="ColumnSpacing" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="RowSpacing" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ContentPage.Resources>


    <!--    DICA 2    -->
    
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <Grid>
        
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       
            <local:PinchToZoomContainer>
            <local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
                    <StackLayout >
                        <Image Source="luciferc.jpg" />
                <Image Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Image Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Image Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                <Image Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
                <Image Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </local:PinchToZoomContainer.Content>
  </local:PinchToZoomContainer>
       
    </Grid>
        </ContentPage.Content>
   
    
  </ContentPage>

in cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using XamarinRocket.ViewModel;

namespace XamarinRocket.Views
{
    public partial class XamarinRocket2Page : ContentPage
    {
        public XamarinRocket2Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
     
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's easy and uses intent, but I can't find anything on the forum, can anyone help?

Comment: This is very hard to understand.  Does this mean, 1) I want to click on a specific image in a grid of images, 2) then navigate to another page with just that selected image?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, exactly Jason

Comment: 1) I want to click on a specific image in a grid of images, 2) then navigate to another page with just that selected image

Answer (score 1):

I get using it:

```
<StackLayout >
                        <ImageButton  Source="luciferc.jpg" x:Name="Button666"
                                 Clicked="ButtonClicked"/>
                        <ImageButton Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="ButtonClicked1"/>
                        <ImageButton Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="ButtonClicked2"/>
                        <ImageButton Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Clicked="ButtonClicked3"/>
                        <ImageButton Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="ButtonClicked4"/>
                        <ImageButton Source="luciferc.jpg" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Clicked="ButtonClicked5"/>
                        
                    </StackLayout>

        public async void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
        public async void ButtonClicked1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
        public async void ButtonClicked2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
        public async void ButtonClicked3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
        public async void ButtonClicked4(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
        public async void ButtonClicked5(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
        }
```

Comment: could you help me on how to open in a view only all the photos as fullscrren?

Answer (score 0):

however it is a lot of xaml and dirty, I would like a full scrren like this:

[How do i Show selected grid image in Full Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218567/how-do-i-show-selected-grid-image-in-full-screen)

```
package com.td.gridview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
    
            // get intent data
            Intent i = getIntent();
    
            // Selected image id
            int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
            ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
        }
    
    }
```